# Basic Python 2D graphics?

Tags: python, graphics, 2d

I'm looking for a Python 2D graphics library that can basically do the following and not necessarily anything more:

- Create a window of specified width and height
- Set the RGB of pixel X, Y on the back buffer.
- Swap buffers

...and that's it basically. I can't find anything that doesn't come with a massive amount of complex baggage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend `PyQt` for this - it's a GUI library/framework but it has very good drawing capabilities. If you look at the examples coming with PyQt, focusing on the graphics & drawing samples, it's quite amazing what you can do with very few lines of code.

Oh, and it does the double-buffering you mention automatically so you don't have to worry about it.

---

Alternatively, you can use `PyGame` - a library wrapping SDL, used for game development. Naturally it has very strong 2D graphics capabilities.